# HTML webpage full screen part 2

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

So I got the webpage to go full screen now but I am using height 100% for all my css attributes and now I am getting a scroll bar on the right side.

http://www6.luc.edu/test/cabplan/maps/index2.html

when i change the #content_container to height 89% it changes it but its looks different on other screen sizes. How do I make it so that the map is always the height up until the footer with the "esri" logo on the bottom right above the footer as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be something better suited for jquery. You can call it to resize the height on load and on window resize.

To get the window height you would use

```
windowHeight = $(window).height();
```

You take this and assign it to a variable and subtract the heights of the header and footer. And in set the css by using

```
${'#content_container').css({width: windowHeight+"px"});
```

Then if someone resizes the window you run the same options in a function like the following

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  //update stuff
});
```

## EDIT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 windowHeight = $(window).height();
 divHeight = windowHeight - 100 - 100; // heights of your header/footer
 $('#content_container').css({height: divHeight+'px'});
});

$(window).resize(function() {
 windowHeight = $(window).height();
 divHeight = windowHeight - 100 - 100; // heights of your header/footer
 $('#content_container').css({height: divHeight+'px'});
});
```

you can replace the 100's for static calls of height by assigning variable and call $('#divid').height(); Since your header is position:absolute, if you subtract the header then you will need to position the div from the top the same px.

To call js include the following before the javascript above.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" />
```

Comment: This sounds like it would work but not sure what to add for the //update stuff part

Comment: it will be the same as you would call when it is the same code that would be called on load. updated code now. Dont forget to include jquery.

Comment: Yes all in a script but it can be in the head or at the bottom of the body. Example of above script: http://jsfiddle.net/EeFz9/

Comment: WOW, this totally worked, after I added this JS code, all I had to do was put the #main-content with top 100px and the scroll left, and my zoom in and out symbols moved down, thanks for you help